# Installing TPM on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, tpm

I have a Sabertooth 990fx revision 2 motherboard, which I've had a number of years and am quite happy with. It is using the 2901 BIOS from 2016, which appears to be the latest available.

I wanted to use BitLocker, so I bought a TPM module - Asus TPM-L R2.0. Plugged that into the motherboard and the BIOS can see the TPM.

However, I cannot get Windows itself to recognise it. I tried with my current Windows installation, that can't see it. That install is a little unstable so next I unplugged all hard disks, installed a new Crucial SSD, disabled the Compatibility Support Module, enabled Secure Boot and then installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 (1809) which as far as I can tell is now using the UEFI boot manager. Still nothing.

The TPM is enabled in BIOS. There is another option to activate it, I try setting that but as soon as the computer reboots (which it does when you save the BIOS settings), the setting is reset (or at least is is no longer set on going back into the BIOS)

Running TPM.msc states that no TPM is installed. I have read posts which state that the TPM should appear as a Security device if properly installed, or potentially a System device if not installed but I can't find it on my system. There doesn't appear to be any special drivers to install.

I'm not familiar with TPM's in order to diagnose the issue.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

I took the chip out of the motherboard and attached a photo in case that is of help.

[image: Photo of TPM]

Comment: It does not sound like you have installed the necessary drivers for the TPM.  You can use BitLocker without a TPM by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. There don't seem to be any drivers that I can tell. Older versions of Windows seemed to need some but 10 doesn't. Asus certainly don't seem to offer any. I believe the chip is really an Infineon, but again drivers are supposed to come from Asus not them.

Answer (score -1):

These ASUS TPM-L (20-1 Pin) modules (and others like it that use an Infineon SLB 9556 chip), have a security vulnerability (CVE-2017-15361) in its firmware. This was of course fixed in updated firmware revisions, but in order to prevent older revisions with the vulnerability to continue to function and therefore present a security risk, an update to Windows 10 was released that disabled any TPM boards that did not contain newer firmware revisions.

As such if you use an affected TPM module, your motherboard will recognise it but Windows 10 (if it has said update) will pretend not to. Some manufacturers did release firmware updates to the modules (SuperMicro being one) but these were apparently rolled into motherboard UEFI updates so the only way to update would be to first update a compatible motherboard then plug the module into that.

Most of these modules are inherently the same (provided they use the same interface and the same Infineon chip), so you can use a SuperMicro TPM 2.0 with the same interface and Infineon chip in an ASUS motherboard that supports it and vice versa.

[This thread](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?96727-Asus-Infineon-TPM-firmware-update) might be of use in regards to actually updating the firmware on the ASUS module, although note that it appears the users in that thread are mostly talking about the newer TPM-M modules ASUS had already started selling, which replaced the TPM-L modules. However while the interface is different the Infineon chip is the same so they should still use the same firmware.

There are instructions in that thread on how to go about updating it using a somewhat unofficial and hacky method - there was one person who managed to use the methods listed in the thread to update his older TPM-L module but he reported some issues and never elaborated on if he fixed them. YMMV.

Bear in mind they may refer to links on ASUS' own website which no longer seem to exist. But thank the various gods for [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20191208060134/https://www.asus.com/Motherboard-Accessories/TPM-M-R2-0/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

Comment: This is OK information, I guess, but it also doesn't answer the question that was asked. It should not be necessary to go to links to get the actual solution in an answer here.